# Angular Directive for a custom Checkbox

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have a set of code that I resuse for custom checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel" name="box" ng-disabled="isDisabled" />
<label class="control-label" for="box"><span></span>I am a Checkbox</label>
```

I'd like to create a custom directive that will replicate this same functionality, something similar to:

```
<custom-checkbox ng-model="myModel" my-label="I am a Checkbox" my-id="checkbox1" ng-disabled="isDisabled"></custom-checkbox>
```

I've searched on all the help papers but cannot figure this out.  I have the following directive, which isn't close to working :(

```
app.directive('customCheckbox', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          ngModel: '=',
          myLabel: '=',
          myId: '=',
          ngDisabled: '=',
        },
        template: '<div><input type="checkbox" id="{{myId}}" ng-disabled="{{ngDisabled}} ng-model="{{ngModel}}"  />' +
        '<label class="control-label" for="{{myId}}" >' +
        '<span></span>{{myLabel}}</label></div>'
    }
});
```

Comment: there is a trailing comma in the scope object

Answer (score 0):

Why are you including all these attributes into the template?

```
    template: '<div><input type="checkbox" id="{{myId}}" ng-disabled="{{ngDisabled}} ng-model="{{ngModel}}"  />' +
    '<label class="control-label" for="{{myId}}" >' +
    '<span></span>{{myLabel}}</label></div>'
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/fL8t2ecj/1/) works.

Besides, "=" implies an angular expression, and "I am a label" is not one.